# What is the importance of Kartik month?

Tags: puranas, skanda-purana

I read on random source about Kartik month which just started. It was written on behalf of Skanda purana that this month is very dear to Lord Vishnu. In this month we gets more merits than other months by doing any good work (charity, devotion etc). In this month, whatever we offer to Gods, they will sure accept it.

I don't know whether this information about importance of kartik month from random source was how much correct Or there is really mentioned in Skanda purana about Kartik month?

Does Skanda Purana really convey Kartik month as favorite month of Lord Vishnu? Any other scriptures says something about the importance of this month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is mentioned in Skanda Purana.

The month Kartik is very dear to Lord Vishnu and any virtuous deed done during this month never goes without 
being rewarded.

One important 
characteristic of this month is that all 
the deities live in the proximity of 
human beings for the entire period of 
the month and accept everything that 
is offered to them.

As per **Significance of the month of Kartika** from [Essence Of Skanda Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana26.html) available on Kama koti website,

Sage Narada enquired of Lord Brahma in this matter and Lord Brahma’s instant reply was that

> the best month of a Year was Kartika, the Supreme Deity to worship was Narayana and the most Sacred Tirtha was Badari Kshetra. As regards Kartika Month, Bhagavan Vishnu always accorded high esteem and whatever good deeds were performed in the ‘Masa’ were fully accepted by all the Devas since they were readily available there through out the month.

Comment: You hv answered the duplicate with the same source I hv used to answer the original.

Comment: @Rickross I didn't know that it's duplicate... :)